# Ruby 1.8.7: group_by with sum in an enumerable type

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have an array of records that is laid out in the following structure:

`[{"some_id" => 2, "some_total => 250}, {"some_id" => 2, "some_total" => 100}, {"some_id" => 3, "some_total" => 50}, {"some_id" => 3, "some_total" => 50}, {"some_id" => 3, "some_total" => 25}, {"some_id" => 1, "some_total" => 10}]`

What's the best way using Ruby's group_by/inject/sum or whatever is available with Enumerable, to have that return an ordered array of hashes, where each hash is keyed by "some_id" and the value is the sum of all that id's "some_total" ordered by the id with the highest total at the beginning of the array? The results would look like the following:

`[{"some_id" => 2, "sum" => 350},
   {"some_id" => 3, "sum => 125},
   {"some_id" => 1, "sum" => 10}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functional approach:

```
hs.group_by { |h| h["some_id"] }.map do |id, hs|
  sum = hs.map { |h| h["some_total"] }.inject(:+) 
  {:some_id => id, :sum => sum}
end.sort_by { |h| -h[:sum] } 

#=> [{:some_id=>2, :sum=>350}, 
#    {:some_id=>3, :sum=>125}, 
#    {:some_id=>1, :sum=>10}]
```